# matlab plot(x,y) of different data type

Tags: matlab, function, datetime, plot

i got data (2945 * 3) of different types imported as cell array. 1st column data type has been imported as text (time e.g 1/1/1990), whereas the  2nd and 3rd columns are numbers.

so far i used **cell2mat** to convert to double both the 2nd and 3rd columns. Thus plot(y) works {y being either the 2nd or 3rd column data} , however i am wondering how i can handle the text data type from my 1st column in an attempt to use plot(x,y).

Any idea would be appreciated. cheers

```
    --------sample.csv-------------
   Date        LAST       Rt
   1/27/2018    20       0.234556
   1/26/2019    20.05   0.184556
   1/23/2040    20.1    0.134556
   1/22/1990    20.15   0.084556
   1/21/1991    20.2    0.034556
   1/20/1993    20.25   -0.015444
   1/19/1998    20.3    -0.065444
   1/16/2050    20.35   -0.115444
   1/15/2030    20.4    -0.165444

--------cell array appearance------------
      1          |    2     |  3
1|   '1/27/2018'   20        0.234556
2|  '1/26/2019'    20.05     0.184556
3|  '1/23/2040'    20.1      0.134556
4|  '1/22/1990'    20.15     0.084556
5|  '1/21/1991'    20.2      0.034556
6|  '1/20/1993'    20.25     -0.015444
7|  '1/19/1998'    20.3      -0.065444
8|  '1/16/2050'    20.35     -0.115444
9|  '1/15/2030'    20.4      -0.165444
```

Comment: am304: x_dates = cellfun(@datenum,test(1,:)). thx i slightly updated it to x_dates = cellfun(@datenum,test(:,1)) in conjunction with plot(x_dates,y),datetick('x','dd/mm/yyyy'). I can therefore confirm that the chart is working fine, although it adds some blank space on the x-axis for some reasons. I think it's purely a cosmetic stuff that i will work on. Cheers mate, as you did help! Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use [`datenum`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) to convert the text to a serial date number (copied from Octave command line):

```
>> test
test =
{
  [1,1] = 1/1/2000
  [1,2] = 1/2/2001
  [1,3] = 10/2/2001
  [1,4] = 10/3/2001
  [1,5] = 10/3/2005
}
>> x_dates = cellfun('datenum',test(:,1))
x_dates =

   730486   730853   731126   731127   732588
>> y = rand(size(x_dates));
>> plot(x_dates,y)
>> datetick('x','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

**Update:**

It looks like `cellfun` requires a function handle in MATLAB, so you probably need to do something like:

```
x_dates = cellfun(@datenum,test(:,1))
```

Comment: am304: solution looks reasonable (converting to serial then switching back to date format), except that x_dates=cellfun('datenum',abrxeur(1,:)) leads from my side to
Error using cellfun
Unknown option. ps: i used the interface to import my csv data. A priori it should not matter compared to your case where test is defined. should it ?

Comment: You need to show us what `abrxeur` looks like, at least the first 10 rows or so, so that we can replicate the issue. Otherwise it's impossible to say what's going on.

Comment: am304: just posted it after editing initial post. hope it helps, cheers.

Comment: Thanks, that shows the content of the csv file, but not what the cell array looks like, which is the critical information that is missing.

Comment: am304: just updated my post as a way around found since i do not have enough reputation to post a picture. it would have been otherwise quicker. does it help actually? cheers

Comment: Thanks, but again, you have formatted it. Can you not just type `abrxeur(1:10,1)` at the MATLAB command line and copy/paste it as text/code? With the data as you have shown it should work.

Comment: OK, I think I know what's wrong. I am using Octave and the code I have posted works well, but in MATLAB it looks like `cellfun` requires a function handle. Will update my answer.

Comment: Please don't make comments while updating the answer, it's very messy (that's what comments are for). I have made it explicit in the answer that the "code" was in fact copied from the command line (I thought it would have been obvious, but apparently not), and swapped the columns and rows around, you were right about that. Please accept the answer if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `XTick` and `XTickLabel`. The former will set up where and how many ticks you want in your X axis (I guess that you'd want one for each X data, but you also may want to go jumping 10 by 10). The second will set the labels in those tick positions. If the Labels are less than the ticks, they will repeat, so careful with that.

Let me illustrate with an example:

```
x = [0 1 2 3];
y = [2 0 1 1];
plot (x, y);

yourstrings={'Banana', 'T', 'Potato', '45'};
set(gca,'XTick',x(1):x(end))
set(gca,'XTickLabel',yourstrings)
```

[image]

A second option would be to use `text`. you could put text wherever you like in the plot. Let me illustrate again. Of course I don't meant to put it "nice", but if you/d like, you could play with offsetting the positions of the texts and so on in order to get a more "beautiful" plot.

```
x = [0 1 2 3];
y = [2 0 1 1];
plot (x, y);

yourstrings={'Banana', 'T', 'Potato', '45'};
for ii=1:length(yourstrings)
    text(x(ii),y(ii),yourstrings{ii})
end
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, got it. but my question focus more on how to handle datetime data imported as text. in your example suppose x=['1/1/1990' '1/2/1990'] ; y=[0.2 0.3]. plot(x,y) will surely lead to Error using plot
Conversion to double from cell is not possible to the extent x needs to be treated 'adequately'.

Comment: I think its quite clear. Do `x1=1:length(x)` being `x` your strings and then use any of the solutions given. @N.E.R.D

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new matrix with usable data (or rewrite your current one) by looping through your matrix(:,1) to convert the strings using the *cellfun* function.

Or just to plot:

```
plot(cellfun(@(x)str2double(x), Measures(:,i)))
```

where i = 1: length(matrix)